# Displaying all permutations of a String in c++ not working for string length above 7

Tags: c++, permutation

So I am using this code to display all the permutations of a given input string.
But this code is not working for strings above length 7. Any advice/solution will be very helpful.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
/* Function to swap two characters */
void swap(char& a, char& b)
{
    char temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}    
/* Function to obtain permutations of string characters */
void permutation(string s,int i,int n)
{
    int j;
    if (i == n)
        cout << s << "\t";
    else
    {
        for (j = i; j < s.length(); j++)
        {
            swap(s[i],s[j]);
            permutation(s, i + 1, n);
            swap(s[i],s[j]);
        } 
    }
}  
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Enter the amino acid string : ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << endl << "The permutations of the given string : " << endl;
    permutation(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working?

Comment: Specifically, it is displaying the results except the last few permutations. It is showing "Runtime Error".

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @Neil try `void permutation(string &s,int i,int n)` (pass the string by reference). Will it help? Maybe you run out of the stack///

Comment: Have you considered using `std::next_permutation()`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: The code looks fine. I've tried it and it works fine for lengths 7,8 and 9. It must be a particular issue with your compiler/computer.

Comment: It works for me with string size 9 on visual studio 2010 express. (only missing `#include<string>`)

Comment: I copied your code and ran it on ideone, it works fine, atleast upto 9 character length

Comment: You claim to get results from your `permutation()` function without any output (reference) parameter??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there is the following line in `permutation()` --> `cout << s << "\t";`

Comment: @AlexLop. .....tried with reference. not working....but thanks still

Comment: @AlexLop. How's that intended to consider any previous permutations?? `cout` writes to the terminal, but doesn't change state of any parameters!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If you tested the code, you'd see that it does exactly what the name implies.

Comment: @vish4071   ........im working on ideone......and for me working till 7......

Comment: @Neil: "im working on ideone". That's your problem. Ideone doesn't allow you to run arbitrarily long programs. You are getting timed out.

Comment: @SHR .......tried with #include<string> ...........no change still......i am working on ideone......VS 2010 Express and Ideone....the small difference might be between them.....

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Might be just output size - at least that's what I saw on coliru. Not sure it's a timing thing necessarily.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley .............that may be the main reason.....i will try on others

Comment: @Barry: Yeah, could be one or the other.

Comment: ofcourse I'm not getting the whole o/p of your code on ideone. If you are practicing such things, try it on your own machine. Try using gcc/g++

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is actually correct, and the problem has nothing to do with the code.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct<sup>†</sup>. The issue you're running into is that whatever online compiler you're running is giving you limited buffer space. For example, on coliru, the simple program:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Does not print 50,000 numbers. It ends at:

```
24082
24083
240
```

I imagine you're seeing the same behavior. It could also, as [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082373/displaying-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-c-not-working-for-string-length-abo#comment52061705_32082373) suggests, be a timing issue. Either way, it's not the code - it's the environment.

---

<sup>†</sup>While technically correct, you should cross-post this to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as the solution can be greatly improved upon.